# PHP displaying ??? instead of hebrew when I show hebrew from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, mariadb

I try to show query in Hebrew from mysql mariadb 10.2 through php. The problem is that all I see is question marks as the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZGJJ.jpg

I changed all the database, tables and columns to UTF8_general_ci. I updated the meta tag, as u can see in the code below, the header, and when I put `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` it says https error 500, so I made it a comment.

config_php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "users";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "users";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
if (!$con) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
//mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$con);
}
```

status.php:

I couldn't post the code for some reason so heres a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8tAy.jpg

So I thought it would give me no question marks, but it did.

Comment: i bet the problem is the rendering charset. what happens if you add `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");` to the top of the script?

Comment: You've said that you've changed all db, tables and columns to UTF8_general_ci. Were the data already in them when they were not UTF8? If that's the case then data in your DB are already corrupted and you won't be able to retrieve them correctly.You would need to fix the data in DB first.

Comment: Yea I did both what you two said, and it still doesnt work.. you can even see in the pictures I uploaded the code you just wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$con);
```

-->

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Even better is to get in the habit of using the OO coding style:

```
$con->mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

If you have further problems, see "quotation mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Do *not* use any of the `mysql_*` functions; they are deprecated and do not work with the `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve it, by changing all the database column and tables to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci 
and adding mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
and adding  to the form.. hope it helps to somone who has the same problem!